# Autosizing GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Is there any lib that can help me to achieve what [CollagePlus jQuery library](http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/) does?

I have a list of pictures (link and dimensions). Dimensions could be different and i need to arrange all images inside one view like in attached screen.

**Update.** I have a listView (RecyclerView), each item could have such gridView - so **layout_height** has to be **wrap_content**.

[image]

I've tried [StaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) - that's not exactly what i want. 
Also tried [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) - very buggy.

Answer (score 3):

the support library there's the new `RecyclerView` that can achieve exactly that, you just have to use the `GridLayoutManager` and supply a `SpanSizeLookup`

here are the links for the docs

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html

Comment: I tried this yesterday, but seems it's hard to put RecyclerView in another RecyclerView :(

Comment: I didn't say you should do such a thing. 1 RecyclerView only. The `SpanSizeLookup` will give to the view the width (a.k.a. "span") that each photo will take and the GridLayoutManager will make it align the way u want.

Comment: I need to have gridview inside item, which is inside RecyclerView.

Comment: Please read again my original answer and the supplied links. I never said anything about `GridView`, you should not use `GridView`. You should use RecyclerView, and each element from the adapter be just the photo.

Comment: By "GridView" i mean RecyclerView arranged by GridLayoutManager, which is inside an item of "main" RecyclerView.

Comment: that's why it's so important to properly state what are you using when asking other ppl for help https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html `listview != recyclerView` and `gridview != gridLayoutManager`. You never mention anything on your question that this whole thing will be inside another recyclerView. To build the layout you draw you don't need one inside the other.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you achieve what you want. It's etsy's staggered grid view. Well supported.

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid